# How to schedule a job to run SPSS modeler in Watson studio

Tags: job-scheduling, watson-studio, spss-modeler

I created SPSS modeler flow in Watson studio. I need to schedule it runs daily, but modeler flows can not be scheduled as job in Watson studio.
What do you suggest to do ?
Maybe thru a notebook which runs the modeler and that can be scheduled afterwards? 
If so, pls advise the Phyton code to run a SPSS modeler built in Watson studio

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@massi Scheduling is currently not available in SPSS modeler flow in Watson Studio.

Comment: yes, you right, that's the challenge.
I was looking for some work around to run the modeler on schedules (e.g. invoking the modeler thru notebook and then setup a schedule on the notebook?).
Any suggestion?

Comment: What I can say for now is there is currently no workaround.

Comment: @jkim Please have a look at the FAQ article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer section _Answer the question_. As I read it, this answer reiterates second sentence of the OP, please consider deleting your post unless you can edit in an answer. Sorry for the harsh points, thank you for trying to help OP.